# Validated optional nested form in Symfony2

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, nested-forms, option-type

Is there a way in Symfony2 to add an optional nested form while using cascade validation?
In other words, say I have a user form with a nested address form (`->add('adresse', new AddressType(), array('required' => false))`). This address is not required BUT must be validated in case the user specify it (`'cascade_validation' => true`).

**UPDATE**

Relevant entities and forms :

User entity (Getters & Setters are classical, Symfony generated):

```
class User
{
    [...]

    /**
     * @var \Address
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", cascade="persist")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *        name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id"
     * )
     */
    private $address;

    [...]
}
```

The address entity is classical, no bidirectionnal relation to user.

User form

```
    class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            [...]
            ->add('address', new AddressType(), array('required' => false))
            [...]
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Xentia\FuneoBundle\Entity\User',
            'cascade_validation' => true
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

The address nested form is classical

As you can see, the is a quite classical and straightforward code. The only particular case is that address is optional. Leading to an validation error only in the case that the address was previously set (and, thus, exist in the DB and as a not null relation with the user) and the user want to unset it (all address fields are left empty).
It seems that if the related address has not an actual instance it can still be optional. But, if an instance of the address exist and is linked with the user, it can not be optional anymore.

*So, what should it do*: When the user update his profile, if there was a previously set address and he try to unset it, `user->address` should be set to NULL and the address should be deleted.
*What does actually happens*: The form throw a validation error saying that the address fields are not set. But, as the address is optional, such validation error should not occur. And, in fact, it does not occur if the address was not set before the user update his profile, it only occurs if there was an address previously set.

Comment: If you use `cascade_validation` and your `Address Entity` has validation rules, they will be applied if your `AddressType` has at least one field with input data

Comment: Great, you're right! I had a select with a default value. I put that value to null and now the validation works. Now it seems to me such a stupid question... sorry!

Comment: Well, it now works when creating a new user. But it does not work if the user already exist and had an address then try to modify his data and unset the address fields.

Comment: Why would you want to unset his address data? If the address entity is set, new property data will be validated nevertheless on form submission.

Comment: The address is optional. So the user can set it first (a new address is created and linked to the user object), then decide to unset all the fields. As the nested address form is set to be "required => false", Symfony should remove the link to the address (and remove the address from the DB). But, instead, the form is invalidated (as the fields are left blank, the validation rules of the address entity dont pass if Symfony try to save it).

Comment: Can you update the question with a full flow of how are things intended to work? And some mappings between these two entities?

Comment: you cannot achieve what your are trying to do by editing the `User` entity. You should make a `Delete Addres` button somewhere and delete that specific entity, also update your relationship to : `targetEntity="Address", cascade="persist", onDelete="SET NULL"` so a user can add a new `Address` in the future

Comment: A "Delete Address" button? It seems to me overkill for the users... I see no reason for that. If the user doesn't set the address, the address should be automatically removed. A software must be easy for the user and hard for the dev, not the contrary. It is definitely not a good solution to me.

Comment: then you have to make this form a  service and delete the address entity from there if it is empty

Comment: I really don't see the point here... why is that so complicated for such a comon task? CakePHP made it so simple. If the child object is empty in the form, it is not created in the DB and if it was already existing in the DB, it was removed from it. Simple as that.
It's nonsense in Symfony. If the user is allowed to unset the child object, why keep it in the DB if he unset it?
I mean, he can no to set it at the create process, but he can't remove it at the update process? I really don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

> When the user update his profile, if there was a previously set address and he try to unset it, user->address should be set to NULL and the address should be deleted.

Yes, your are right, if the user tries to unset it it shout be deleted. Further down in our comments you clarified a bit more:

> A "Delete Address" button? It seems to me overkill for the users... I see no reason for that. If the user doesn't set the address, the address should be automatically removed. A software must be easy for the user and hard for the dev, not the contrary. It is definitely not a good solution to me.

This is not how it should work. Since a *user* has previously created an *address* there is no point on deleting this `Address` entity just because all it's properties are empty. If you were to delete your **user** then you'd *maybe* want to delete its **address**. For Doctrine there is no need to delete an association if it is not explicitly said so (*or cascaded*).

What you are trying to achieve may not be straight forward with [Constraint Configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/validation.html#constraint-configuration). You should make your entity validation ***internal*** so to speak.

Set up your [Callbacks](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/constraints/Callback.html) in your `Address` class. Can be something like this:

```
    /**
     * @param ExecutionContextInterface $contextInterface
     */
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $contextInterface)
    {
        $country = ($this->country && $this->state);
        $home = ($this->street && $this->zip);

        if ($country || $home) {
            //You can start validating your fields one by one as you wish
            if ($this->country === null) {
                $contextInterface->addViolationAt('country', 'Pick a Country, mercì');
            }

            [...]
        }
        //No property is set so we skip validation (they can be set as empty in the DB)            
        return;
    }
```

### Note

You can use the validation [constraints](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/constraints.html) inside your entity or a total [custom](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) class for your validation needs.